# bash script to run everyday but not the 1st of each month

Tags: linux, bash, shell, if-statement

im writing more bash backup scripts but have a little problem.

on the 1st of each month i run server1.sh to do a full backup.
every other day i run server2.sh which looks at server1 backup and performs an incremental backup based on this full backup.

thats all great.

my first problem is how can i tell server2.sh to NOT run on the 1st of each month as server1.sh will be running this day.

to run these scripts im using crontab.

example cron

- 0 1 * * server1.sh
- 2 * * * server2.sh

so far i have this script using an if but its not fully working yet

```
#!/bin/bash


LinkDest=/home/backup/website/full
r_date=$(date "+%d-%m-%y")
f_date=$(date +%F)
c_date=$(date +%d)
servers=("123.123.78.90" "123.123.78.91" "123.123.78.92" "123.123.78.93" "123.123.78.94" "123.123.78.95" "cluster")

if [ $c_date -eq 01 ]
  then
      echo "Backup Skipped 1st of Month" 
      exit 0

  else    

for j in "${servers[@]}"
do

echo "server:/data/backup/$j /home/backup/website/$j"

rsync -avz --link-dest=$LinkDest root@123.123.78.90:/data/backup/"$j"     /home/backup/website/$f_date --bwlimit=10000 --log-file=/logs/rsync_"$j"_"$r_date".log

fi
done
```

Comment: It might work a tad better if you reversed the "fi" and "done" lines.

Comment: Bruce. that worked a treat thanks

Answer (score 2):

This is the format of cron expression:

```
# Minute   Hour   Day of Month       Month          Day of Week        Command    
# (0-59)  (0-23)     (1-31)    (1-12 or Jan-Dec)  (0-6 or Sun-Sat)                
    0        2          12             *                *            /usr/bin/find
```

Given your question, you can use following cron expression:

- All days except first day of the month for run `server2.sh`: `0 0 2-31 * *`
- Only first day of month for run `server1.sh`: `0 0 1 * *`

You have to define minute and hour at which run your script. So replace first two 0 0 with your own values. For example:

```
20 3 2-31 * *
20 3 1 * *
```

To run your scripts at 3.20 AM.

Hope this help!

Comment: i forgot all about date ranges in cron. thanks that would work fine too